# What causes a "Virtual Memory exhausted" error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, allocation

Alright.. Here's the thing.. I am building an app in which when the user taps on download button it downloads a bunch on images (296, to be exact).

In simulator everything works flawless, on my iPhone (4S) on around 100th image it crashes with error:

> malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size= "some random number") failed (error code= 3)*** error: can't allocate region
>
> libBacktraceRecording.dylib:  allocate_free_list_pages() -- virtual memory exhausted!

Here's the code I wrote for downloading those images:

```
-(void)getData
{
    NSError *error;
    int i;
    NSArray *brojLinije = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"linije" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *urlSlike = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"urlSlike" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *pocetno = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pocetno" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *sortiranje = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sort" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray*paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *desktopDir = [paths firstObject];
    UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    for (i = 0; i<296; i++) {

        NSString *brojLinije1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[brojLinije objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSString *pocetno1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [pocetno objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSString *tableSort = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [sortiranje objectAtIndex:i]];
        image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.busevi.com/images/stories/Red-Voznje/Gradski-Prevoz-BG/linija.%@.png", [urlSlike objectAtIndex:i ] ]]]];
        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.1)];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
        NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

        NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.jpg",desktopDir,[urlSlike objectAtIndex:i]];
        [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

        [newManagedObject setValue:brojLinije1 forKey:@"brojLinije"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:data1 forKey:@"imageData"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:pocetno1 forKey:@"pocetnoStajaliste"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:tableSort forKey:@"sort"];
        NSLog(@"%d / 296", i);
    }

    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

Only thing I know is that the image allocation frequency (too much allocating and no time to automatically release) is making the problem, AND that I have tried every method I know so far, AND I HAVE watched A LOT of "Instruments" app tutorials and only one helped (to find the source of filling virtual memory) but I still can't solve my problem.

Comment: Is it running in a background thread?

Comment: Not relevant to the answer, as I think user3386109 has already given it, but you don't need `NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.1)];`, just NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.1);`. That might save a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using SDWebImage framework I encountered a lot of bugs and unanswered crashes from the app. SDWebImage is awesome if the count of images that are about to be downloaded is lower that, let's say 50. Because, when downloading one by one image that are showed in TableViewCell + fast scrolling (fast flicking), the app receives memory warning a couple of times while the TableView is still scrolling (SDWebImage will clear memory ONLY when TableView is slowly scrolling or not scrolling at all) so it crashes the app.

So my only solace with app crashing while downloading 300+ images was simple Apple's method called `dispatch_async`. More about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html).

And this is how I solved my problem (I just had to move everything from my original `-(void)getdata` method to `dispatch_async` block. DONE!
So now it looks like this:

```
-(void)getData {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
        slike = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"slike" ofType: @"plist"]];
        brojevi = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"linije" ofType:@"plist"]];
        pocetnaStajalista = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pocetno" ofType:@"plist"]];
        sort = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sort" ofType:@"plist"]];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Linija" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSString *brojLinije;
        NSString *pocetnoStajaliste;
        NSString *sortiranje;
        NSData *data;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];

        for (int i = 0; i<314; i++) {
            NSManagedObject *novaLinija = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            brojLinije = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",brojevi[i]];
            pocetnoStajaliste = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pocetnaStajalista[i]];
            data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.busevi.com/images/stories/Red-Voznje/Gradski-Prevoz-BG/linija.%@.png",slike[i]]]];
            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            sortiranje = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", sort[i]];

            [novaLinija setValue:data forKey:@"slikaLinije" ];
            [novaLinija setValue:brojLinije forKey:@"brojLinije"];
            [novaLinija setValue:pocetnoStajaliste forKey:@"pocetnoStajaliste"];
            [novaLinija setValue:sortiranje forKey: @"sort"];
            NSLog(@"%d / 314", i+1);
            NSError *error;
            [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        } }
```

Hope this helps others with same problem. Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a local [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI) inside of the loop to immediately release any objects that were created in the body of the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i<296; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        // loop body goes here...

    }
}
```

Comment: ... and if he weren't to do that then the original downloaded data, the decoded image and up to two copies of its JPG encoding would be added to the total bottleneck memory cost every single iteration.

Comment: WOW! Thanks everyone for such a quick answers! 
I already did auroreleasepool block, it did 1 part of cleaning memory up just a liiiittle bit, but not the allocation. One of programers said I have to get rid of it and not use it, since I have ARC enabled, but even if I disable it and use a local _release_ or _dealloc_ it still does the same thing.
Thanks @Tommy for tip it did a good work but still, I get the same error.

’'*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libBacktraceRecording.dylib:  allocate_free_list_pages() -- virtual memory exhausted!'’

Comment: [@Yuchen Zhong](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1035008/yuchen-zhong) it's not a background thread, It's a single view tableView app. Something similar to Master-detail app template.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovic Perhaps if the `context` was truly local to the loop, then it would auto-save and release at the bottom of the loop. As written, it seems that `context` is just another pointer to `self.managedObjectContext`. Is that true?

Comment: @user3386109 this is in my "viewDidLoadMethod" `AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;` look at [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52543178/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-11%20at%2012.54.21%20AM.gif) this is the graf of instruments and the results from you and @Tommy are THE BEST .... so far.. I really don't know why, but I still get the same error when I run the app on the iPhone. I'll try few more times tomorrow, and if it works, I'll will surely confirm your answer. Thank you, again!

Comment: @user3386109 Here you go my [.m](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52543178/SveLinijeTableViewController.m) and [.h](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52543178/SveLinijeTableViewController.h) files of tableView, and [here are the results](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52543178/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-11%20at%201.13.17%20AM.gif) again..

Comment: If your question is "Does it saves downloaded/created `newManagedObject`?", the answer is YES. It saves, but NEVER goes to the last one (296th). It always crashes somewhere around 100th (usually from 95th - 115th). Any clues? _tip: I tried to start increasement from 80th or 90th, and it crashed around 190th._

Comment: I think that what's happening is that the app has a single `managedObjectContext`. So when the loop creates a `newManagedObject`, it is held in memory by the global context. I believe the solution is to create a `UIManagedDocument` in the loop, and get the `context` from the document. When the document goes out of scope, it will auto-save and release the `newManagedObject`. At least that's my theory, I have very limited experience with managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Used all of your and my suggestions and possible solutions, but, I'm sorry, none worked.

The point in this case, when app needs to download A LOT of photos, you really should use [SDWebImageDownloader Class Reference](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Classes/SDWebImageDownloader.html).

I know It's frustrating to change the whole method and to realize the previous method (of downloading photos) is useless, so [HERE](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html) is the tutorial and example on how to use SDWebImageDownloader Class. Good Luck.